# Parsing JSON Array

Tags: java, parsing, simplejson

I'm trying to print company list.

My JSON object:

```
{
    "Name": "crunchify.com",
    "Author": "App Shah",
    "Company List": [
        "Compnay: eBay",
        "Compnay: Paypal",
        "Compnay: Google"
    ]
}
```

code:

```
public class ProductTypeParser {

    public  void parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject) throws ParseException {



        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) jsonObject;
        String name = (String) object.get("Name");
        System.out.println(name);

        String age = (String) object.get("Author");
        System.out.println(age);

        //loop array        
        JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) object.get("Company List"); 
        Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }       
    }
}
```

Error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [contextServlet] in context with path [/SpringSafeHouseService2.0] 
  threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray] 
  with root cause java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
```

Comment: Just a side note: you should refactor your names before you put your code into production. ;) - `String age = (String) object.get("Author");` ...

Comment: It says right in the error message: you can't cast an `ArrayList` to a `JSONArray`. Can you just do something like this maybe? : `ArrayList msg = object.get("Company List");`

Comment: How are you actually parsing the json string? Your method doesn't do any real parsing - that's already been done when you created that initial `JSONObject` instance.

Comment: how you have created the JSONObject which is you are passing to this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json-simple (which you seem to be using although the version is missing so my information might be outdated) normally creates an instance of `JSONArray` (which extends `ArrayList` btw.) for arrays in json strings, i.e. your `"Company List"` field.

However, you are also able to pass in a different `ContainerFactory` which might create a different `List` instance for arrays so that might be the reason your cast doesn't work (again there's too little information in your question to further comment on that).

Finally, since you should get a `List` anyways it should be safe to cast to that:

```
List<?> msg = (List<?>) object.get("Company List");
```

Answer (score 3):

Cast into ArrayList instead of JSONArray (because can be a JSONArray or an ArrayList or an implementation of List it's depends how you deserialize your string so use an ArrayList or the interface List ensure you can't have a Class cast exception):

```
JSONObject parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) parser.parse("{\n" +
            "    \"Name\": \"crunchify.com\",\n" +
            "    \"Author\": \"App Shah\",\n" +
            "    \"Company List\": [\n" +
            "        \"Compnay: eBay\",\n" +
            "        \"Compnay: Paypal\",\n" +
            "        \"Compnay: Google\"\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "}"); // Here there is a JSONArray for companies property

    Map<String, Object> obj = new HashMap();
    List<String> companies = new ArrayList<>();
    companies.add("a");
    companies.add("b");
    companies.add("c");
    obj.put("Name", "toto");
    obj.put("Author", "titi");
    obj.put("Company List", companies);
    JSONObject object2 = new JSONObject(obj); // here you have an ArrayList for companies property

    String name = (String) object.get("Name");
    System.out.println(name);

    String age = (String) object.get("Author");
    System.out.println(age);

    //loop array
    List msg = (List) object.get("Company List");
    Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `JSONArray msg = object.getJSONArray("Company List");` instead of `JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) object.get("Company List");`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `org.json.simple` which has a different interface.

Here is how you iterate over the `ArrayList`

```
 for(String s : object.get("Company List"))
      System.out.println(s);
```